# How to set Level3_Shift to Caps Lock AND Compose to Caps Lock+Ctrl in XFCE?

Tags: keyboard-layout, xfce, xmodmap, capslock, compose-key

I switched from SUSE recently, which uses KDE as a default desktop environment. In KDE, it is possible to archieve such a setup with GUI options, but not in XFCE.

I've tried set up the `~/.Xmodmap` file the following way:

```
clear Lock
clear Control
clear Mod2 
clear Mod5 
keycode  77 = Caps_Lock Num_Lock Caps_Lock Num_Lock
keycode  66 = ISO_Level3_Shift ISO_Level3_Shift ISO_Level3_Shift ISO_Level3_Shift
keycode  37 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L NoSymbol Multi_key Multi_key 
add Control = Control_L Control_R
add Lock = Caps_Lock
add Mod2 = Num_Lock
add Mod5 = ISO_Level3_Shift
```

What happens:

- <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> functionality goes to <kbd>Num Lock</kbd>
- <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> functionality goes to <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Num Lock</kbd>

What I expected to happen, but it did not:

- <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> button should be `ISO_Level3_Shift` (it is, according to `xev`, but it has the functionality of usual <kbd>Shift</kbd> somewhy)
- Pressing <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> + Left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> should act as Compose key (does not work).

What am I doing wrong? Xubuntu 18.04, fresh installation

Comment: If you did it in KDE using system settings, it's probably easier to do it via `xkb` options. Please tell us how you did it in KDE.

Comment: Seems that you put the compose key on the fifth and sixth level, not the third level: `keycode  37 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L NoSymbol Multi_key Multi_key `.  Shouldn’t it be something like: `keycode  37 = Control_L NoSymbol Multi_key …`?

Answer (score 0):

Map the third level shift to `<CAPS>` (caps lock) and use the third level of left control as the compose key (`Multi_key`):

```
setxkbmap -option compose:lctrl-altgr \
    -option lv3:caps_switch \
    -layout "us(intl)"
```

For the numlock key you can make a symbols file as a wrapper for whatever layout you are using (I am going to use `us(intl)`).  Make a symbols file named `custom` :

```
xkb_symbols "basic" {

    // The layout that you want to use.
    include "us(intl)"

    key <NMLK> { [
        Caps_Lock, Num_Lock, Caps_Lock, Num_Lock
    ] };

};
```

Save the `custom` file in a directory tree which mirrors the structure of `/usr/share/X11/xkb`.  So if your directory is stored at `/home/<user>/my-xkb/`, the `custom` file should be at `/home/<user>/my-xkb/symbols/custom`.

(See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/506185/185805) for general instructions on how to make and use custom Xkb files.)

Instead of just using `setxkbmap` you’re going to have to use the `-print` option in order to pipe the output to `xkbcomp`.  `xkbcomp` has the `-I` option which you’ll use to give the path to your custom Xkb directory tree.

```
setxkbmap -option compose:lctrl-altgr \
    -option lv3:caps_switch \
    -layout "custom" \
    -print |
        xkbcomp -I"/home/<user>/my-xkb" \
            - "$DISPLAY"
```